# MySQL constraint to attribute

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have this DB structure:

[image]

Is there a way to add constraint additionally and explicit to a certain attribute (column) of the table `pqs` ? For example to `bdm` ?

Or to define the relevant attribute or to define a connection to the relevant attribute in `pqs` somehow ?

Comment: What type of constraint you would add ? Some of them might be added without column dropping (like NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY, DEFAULT) some of them require recreating column (PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT). For simple case example it might done with sql script like this *ALTER TABLE pqs MODIFY bdm INT(11) NOT NULL;*

Comment: I don't really know how I exactly mean it. Somehow I just have the feeling that having the attributes (columns) in the table `pqs` is right, and having the connection in the table `av` to the table `pqs` through `pqs_id` is also right, and I would love to be able to define somehow a more explicit relation to one specific `attribute` in `pqs`, but this doesn't seem to fit together. Maybe I have a flaw in my logic. Maybe I should introduce a new table between the two... ?

Comment: You could  use sql scripts instead db editor - using sql script is more flexible than editor.

Comment: you probable need some like that for adding relationships between tables: `ALTER TABLE AV ADD CONSTRAINT FK_psq_av  FOREIGN KEY (psq_is) REFERENCES PQS(id);` It should help to reproduce your case with table relationships

Comment: Nope, sorry I think it's not what I need. This relationship exists already. The question is how can I create relationship to a specific attribute.

Comment: It was just example .You could add new relationship with the same way. Create table IP (or it might be already existed) and execute sql script to bind ip_id from pqs table with id from IP table  `ALTER TABLE pqs ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ip_psq FOREIGN KEY (ip_id) REFERENCES IP(id);`